# Vertical align with Sass, Susy and Compass

Tags: sass, susy-compass

Any help is much appreciated. I'm using Sass, Compass and Susy to redesign my website. I'm needing to figure out how I can set up a vertical center in browser. I have a row with five columns and I need to center it vertically.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="layout">
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</div>
```

The sections create the row of columns. I need to center the .layout class vertically.

Comment: You can vertically center elements with transform (better browser support) or flexbox; see http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/AbxGr?editors=110 for some examples. Please post a more descriptive example of your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For any issue like this, start by solving for vertical-centering in CSS. The two best methods I know, only work in modern browsers. The best option is [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), followed by a [little trick](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) using `position` and `transform`. There are other solutions if you search around for "css vertical center".

Both of those require prefixing to work across browsers, which is where Compass might be helpful. Compass has mixins to help with both flexbox and transforms.

Comment: I've seen several position / tranform CSS tricks online, but they require that element have a height. My .layout element does not have a set height so the it transforms incorrectly.

Comment: The trick I linked does not require a set height (but the site is down?). Use `position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` — the top positioning is relative to the container, and the transform is relative to the element you are centering, so they combine to give you a perfect center.